# How to split strings in lists

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, split

I have a text in a file with multiple lines. I would like to create one big list, with each line as a seperate list inside. Within these lists each word should be a string. This is my code at the moment, I am failling to split the strings within the lists.

```
f = open("test.txt","r")

for line in f.readlines():
line2= line.split(",")
print(line2)

f.close()
```

This is the output:

```
['Das ist 1e\n']
['Textdatei', '\n']
['bestehend aus mehreren WÃ¶rtern.']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    out = [line.rstrip('\n').split(',') for line in f]
```

i.e. iterate over the lines of the file object (which is an *iterator*), `strip` off the newline at the end and `split` the line on comma.

Note that, if you want to strip off whitespaces from both start and end, use `line.strip()` instead. Also, the file would be opened in `rt` (read-text) mode by default, so you can drop the explicit declaration of the mode parameter, if you want.

---

**Edit:**

It seems you have space separated words, in that case use `split()`:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    out = [line.rstrip('\n').split() for line in f]
```

Comment: thank you, but how do I make each word a string? This is the output I am hoping for: [ ['Das','ist','1e'], ['Textdatei.'] ]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner for that.

```
[line.split(',') for line in Path('test.txt').open('r').read().split('\n')]
```